# SEDE doesn't age well (aka don't let users input their Birthday on SEDE and stop showing their age)

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, age

Stack Exchange has removed anything related to age from their live database recently, following the GDPR, in the database level, including in the tables used by SEDE.

However, SEDE itself still let us put our birthday when editing our profile:

> [image: Birthday field when editing SEDE profile]

More than that, when saving, **age is actually showing up**:

> [image: age showing in SEDE profile]

As far as I could tell, SE wiped previous data so for most users age is blank, but for those who edited after the wipe, age would show up.

Can this please be fixed so that SEDE is synchronized with Stack Exchange and not show/input anything related to age?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created a pull request [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/89) that removes those fields from the Show and Edit view, as well from the User model and the controler.

Additionally I created a migration script to remove the column from the Users table completely.

When that pull request survives the scrutinizing from Nick he is the one that needs to merge it and put it into production.

Comment: Cheers, will accept the answer when Nick will work his magic then.

Comment: @Shadow9 The magic has been worked; the question was tagged completed.